# facing an issue converting umm-al-qura date into gregorian in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have an issue converting the date below into Gregorian  date,

السبت 29 ربيع الثاني 1443

i dont know if the reason is because the date is formatted as a text, i tried format cells to convert it into hijri date with numbers only and it didnt work,

i tried the code below and its only working with dates that inculding numbers only:

```
Function ConvertDate(ByRef StringIn As String) As String
    Dim SavedCal As Integer
    Dim d As Date
    Dim s As String
    
    SavedCal = Calendar
    Calendar = 1
    d = CDate(StringIn)
    Calendar = 0
    s = CStr(d)
    ConvertDate = Format(s, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Calendar = SavedCal
End Function
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is the date in variable _d_ correct? Try to use _d_ in the _format_ method and not the string _s_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel cannot interpret dates that include the Weekday name. So you need to `Split` that from the string. Then changing the Calendar appropriately should work.

```
Function HtoG(S As String) As Date
 
 Calendar = vbCalHijri
 HtoG = CDate(Split(S, " ", 2)(1))
 Calendar = vbCalGreg
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: That worked just like a charm, thanks so much!

Comment: @NayefAl-Zahrani Glad to help. Since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).